# order of tables in FROM clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

For an sql query like this.

```
Select  * from TABLE_A a 
JOIN TABLE_B b 
  ON a.propertyA = b.propertyA
JOIN TABLE_C 
  ON b.propertyB = c.propertyB
```

Does the sequence of the tables matter. It wont matter in results, but do they affect the performance?

One can assume that the data in table C is much larger that a or b.

Comment: That will heavily depend on the database. A decent database has a "cost-based optimiser" that will find the optimal plan regardless of join order. Simpler databases (very simple ones in this case) may not be as sophisticated. What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For each sql statement, the engine will create a query plan. So no matter how you put them, the engine will chose a correct path to build the query.

More on plans you have http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan

There are ways, considering what RDBMS you are using to enforce the query order and plan, using hints, however, if you feel that the engine does no chose the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes  Order of table creates a difference here,(when you are using different joins)

Actually our Joins working on Cross Product Concept

If you are using query like this `A join B join C`

It will be treated like this `(A*B)*C)`

Means first result comes after joining A and B table then it will make join with C table

So if after inner joining A (100 record) and B (200 record) if it will give (100 record)

And then these ( 100 record ) will compare with (1000 record of C)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Well, there is a very, very tiny chance of this happening, see [this article by Jonathan Lewis](http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2006/11/03/table-order/).  Basically, the number of possible join orders grows very quickly, and there's not enough time for the Optimizer to check them all.  The sequence of the tables may be used as a tie-breaker in some very rare cases.  But I've never seen this happen, or even heard about it happening, to anybody in real life.  You don't need to worry about it.